# What would be the proper HTTP status code if the agent's IP is blocked?

Tags: php, http

I'm working on an PHP and MySQL based IP block system that is supposed to block all user agents from specific countries. Which status code should I use if an agent is blocked?

EDIT: I'll elaborate just a little more: I'm concerned about how search engines such as Google might react to it. Is there a possibility that a same search engine might crawl a page two times and get conflicting statuses on both occasions? Are, say, Google bots always "American?"

Comment: Your edit makes it unclear what you're asking and may need a whole other question. [Here is one discussion I found, though](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4497651.htm), and [here's this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/TbpNyFiJvjs)

Comment: I'd also provide some textual explanation like "your country is blocked from accessing our site"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For future reference, here's a big list: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

I'd say you can just do:

```
http_response_code(403);
```

403 is the error for forbidden.

Comment: One would **not** use `401` as that implies the user can authorize to get access.

Comment: What sjagr said. In particular "[The server generating a 401 response MUST send a WWW-Authenticate header field (Section 4.1) containing at least one challenge applicable to the target resource.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1)"

Comment: The more relevant list is maintained by IANA...